# Does the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_9$ contain a noncyclic subgroup of order 9?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

In general does $\mathfrak{S}_{p^2}$ contain a noncyclic subgroup of order $p^2$?

Comment: More generaly, look for Sylow's theorem.

Comment: I am not sure how Sylow's theorem will be useful here because in $\mathfrak{S}_{p^2}$, the Sylow$-p$ subgroup will be (in almost all cases) of much higher order than $p^2$, in fact it will be of order $p^{p+1}$ (I think).

Comment: I think that from there, one can sho there exists subgroups of order $p^d$ for all $0 \leqslant d \leqslant p+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subgroup generated by the cycles $(1,2,\ldots,p)$ and $(p+1,p+2,\ldots,2p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the cycle $(1 \, 2\, 3 \dots p^2)$, the cyclic group generated will be of order $p^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a condition -- see edited post.